# JSON: Insert and retrieve from database(DB2)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a requirement to insert a JSON string into a database(DB2). I do not think I can use a VARCHAR data type here because the maximum limit I was told for a column in DB2 is 32,672. The JSON I wish to insert into this column might have a lot more characters. So, I thought of a blob as a data type. I am able to insert successfully. But while retrieving, I am unable to cast the blob object into the original JSON. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class DerbyBlobDemo
{
private static String url      = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test";
private static String username = "APP";
private static String password = "APP";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    insert();

    read();
}

static void insert() throws Exception
{
    Connection conn = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);


        String jsonSql = "INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE "
            + "(ID, JSON) " + "VALUES (?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(jsonSql);

        stmt.setString(1, "014");

        File jsonFile = new File("path to my json");
        fis = new FileInputStream(jsonFile);
        stmt.setBinaryStream(2, fis);

        stmt.execute();

        conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fex)
    {
        fex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fis != null)
        {
            fis.close();
        }
        if (conn != null
            && !conn.isClosed())
        {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}

static void read() throws Exception
{
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        Statement select = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("Select * from SCHEMA.TABLE");
        while (result.next())
        {
            String identifier = result.getString("ID");

            String json = result.getBlob("JSON").toString();

            JSONObject jsonresult = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json);

            // JSONArray arrayObj = JSONArray.fromObject(result.getBlob("JSON"));

            // JSONArray arrayObj = new JSONArray();
            System.out.println(jsonresult);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 has a column type called a "CLOB" which is the same as a SQL Text type (I think)

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_largeobjectdatatypes.htm

Have you tried that?

Comment: Not yet. Thanks. I think this will solve my problem. Will keep the forum posted if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The [Blob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) interface doesn't state any contract for *toString()* so it is likely returning the value as per the [Object implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). After all, there is no standard way to convert an arbitrary sequence of bytes to a UTF-16 *String*.

So, this line isn't going to work:

```
String json = result.getBlob("JSON").toString();
```

You're using [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) and not Jackson as is tagged in the question (I don't know why you'd need both.)

Assuming the file is encoded as UTF-8, you could parse the data using this method:

```
static Object parseJson(Blob blob) throws SQLException, IOException,
    ParseException {
  try (InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
      Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    return new JSONParser().parse(reader);
  }
}
```

If you need to guard against the possibility that the JSON file is some other Unicode encoding, detection methods are described in detail [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/java-detecting-json-character-encoding.html).